# Swagger JSDoc does not loading API files from sub folders

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-jsdocs

I am integrating swagger doc for a project in node.js and express framework,

**NPM:** Swagger JSDoc - ^4.0.0 [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc)

**Below is folder structure:** (*Note: module-1, module-2 and module-3 are folders!*)

```
 - app 

   - module-1 
      - module-1.controller.js
      - module-1.model.js
      - module-1.route.js
   - module-2 
      - module-2.controller.js
      - module-2.model.js
      - module-2.route.js
   - module-3 
      - module-3.controller.js
      - module-3.model.js
      - module-3.route.js
```

**Working Example:**

```
swaggerJSDoc({
    swaggerDefinition: {
        ...require('../swagger.json')
    },
    apis: [
        './app/module-1/*',
        './app/module-2/*'
        './app/module-3/*'
    ]
})
```

***Node:*** I don't want to add module path every time when i create a new module like above example.

**What i am expecting is below example:** I want to set it one time like set main folder/file path and it will load API Doc data automatically from provided main folder/file path.

I tries below example but its **not working with `/app/*`**:

```
swaggerJSDoc({
    swaggerDefinition: {
        ...require('../swagger.json')
    },
    apis: [
        './app/*'
    ]
})
```

Please guide if is there any way to do this, Any kind of suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should work

```
apis: ['./app/**/*.js'],
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

Given the following project structure

```
- src
  - application
    - routes/
        admin.routes.js
        job.routes.js
  - app.js
```

in `app.js` I had my configuration as follows:

```
const specs = swaggerJsdoc({
  definition: {
    info: {
      title: 'Bank API',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
  },
  apis: [`./application/routes/*.js`],
});
```

changing to:

```
const specs = swaggerJsdoc({
  definition: {
    info: {
      title: 'Bank API',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
  },
  apis: [`${__dirname}/application/routes/*.js`],
});
```

made it work

Comment: `./` will get from current folder, that is why it works. The real problem from the question is that he wants some kind of recursive search, which `**/*` pattern helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, because the operation definitions were located in a different folder.

- Use *__dirname* to step on the current folder.
- Use path.join to make a clear and easy-to-read path.
- Move to the intended folder where the definitions live.
- Use /** to grab all folders recursively.
- And finally, use /*.js with the file extension

For example:

```
apis: [path.join(__dirname, '/../../src/controllers/**/*.js')
```